# I can't find the file /.vnc/xstartup?

Tags: 14.04, remote-desktop, vnc

I'm using ubuntu 14.04.

I have installed the VNC by using this command

```
sudo apt-get install vnc4server
```

I have tested the connection and it working and the terminal of other system got open.

Now I'm trying for the VNC full desktop.

For that I need to change the last line of /.vnc/xstartup to

```
gnome-session &
```

But I can not find the /.vnc folder. I searched everywhere.

Where can I find this folder /.vnc and file "xstartup".

Does "xstartup" file is stored in any other folder?

Comment: just FYI... you have to actually run vncserver before the folders get automatically created!  just installing vnc4server doesn't create the folders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `~/.vnc` not `/.vnc` - meaning a hidden directory (`.vnc`) at the top level of your home directory (`~/`).

Just open a file browser and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or select "Show Hidden Files" from the "View" menu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have find the file. I want to open the xstartup file in terminal using vim editor. So the command will be "sudo vim ~/.vnc/xstartup" Is this correct?

Comment: No `sudo` please, that is unnecessary and may cause ownership problems

Comment: I can't find the xstartup file in .vnc. Should I want to create that?

Comment: Yes you will need to create it if you want something other than the default gray background + terminal - see [Customising your session](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#Customising_your_session)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I'm trying for ubuntu desktop in VNC. So I create the file. Once again Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just a heads up - the full (Unity-based) Ubuntu desktop doesn't play well with VNC in my experience - you will likely find that a 'lighter' desktop works better